# VBA Excel Search value from range and hide row if found

Tags: excel, vba

I got error `type mismatch`

I am doing matrix here, if a row contains `"x"` then code should keep a row visible. Rows with no `"x"` should be hided. Variable `hideEmptyRows` gets triggered from the button.

```
If (hideEmptyRows = True) Then

        For i = 8 To lastRow

            If Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, lastColumn)).value = "x" Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If

        Next i

    End Ifenter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Object of type `Range` doesn't have such property as `Value`. You need to loop through whole range in order to check if any of cells within the range has value of "x".

You should add to your code:

```
ifContains = false ' variable, which indicates if the value is present in current row
For j = 3 To lastColumn
    If Cells(i, j).Value = "x" Then
        ifContains = true
    End If
Next j
```

Comment: Thank you Mate! With your hints I proceed in my work.